# Java REGEX: matching comments and NOT matching specific character

Tags: java, regex, comments, pattern-matching

so I'm new to Java and having some trouble with regex. I'm trying to find winged comments (`/* */`) and end of line comments( `//` ) in a string so I can split along them and put the pieces in an array.

This is the regex I'm currently have:

```
stringofstuff.split("[!//.*?\n!]");
```

and it works, but my problem is that it's also matching the character "." so when the string contains a number like `90.55`, my array looks like `[90, 55]` which is NOT what I want. I've tried adding `^\\.` to the end of the regex after the closing square bracket:

```
stringofstuff.split("[!//.*?\n!]^\\.");
```

and it succeeds in not matching `.` but it no longer recognizes either type of comment! I have no clue where I'm going wrong, any suggestions?

Comment: For the record you're going to fail in many cases still.  e.g. `System.out.println("/*");` and there are far subtler corner cases.  This can't be done with regex properly.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool - you need a parser. Also, you would currently be getting both non-ccmments between comments and comments from your split.

Comment: Thank you guys, you're absolutely right. As someone else answered, I solved this problem by using the Pattern/Matcher tool in Java to find the group I needed, and deleting from it's start index to its end index. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern and matcher of regex package to do so.
For example to find digits:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if(m.find())
{
     System.out.println(m.start()+" "+m.end()+" "+m.group);
}
```

Similarly you can make different combinations of strings you want to separate out and they will be stored in m.group().

For different combinations and more information on regex package you can see here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

Comment: thank you so much, this turned out to be just what I needed--very helpful link. Turns out I needed a completely different approach to my problem. Again, thank you.